# Singleton-EJB concurency with a container-managed transaction

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, transactions, singleton

I have a Singleton-EJB, that reads all objects from a database with a specific state. Then I do something with these objects and set the state to someting else:

```
@Singleton
public class MyEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPu")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
    public void doSomeStuffAndClose() {
        List<MyObj> objects = getAllOpenObjects();
        for (MyObj obj : objects) {
            // do some stuff here...
            obj.setClosed(true);
        }
    }

    private List<MyObj> getAllOpenObjects() {
        TypedQuery<MyObj> q = em.createQuery("select o from MyObj o "
            + "where o.closed = false", MyObj.class);
        return q.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Now, if i would like to ensure that my method cannot be called concurently, I add the annotation `@Lock(LockType.WRITE)`. But the transaction that sets the states in the database is committed AFTER the lock was released and it is possible that the next caller grabs the same objects again.

How could I prevent this?

Comment: Read about transaction isolation level.

Comment: Why not make `doSomeStuffAndClose` synchronized?

Comment: @frostjogla Thank you for your comment, it was very interesting. So the solution would be to set the isolation level to "serializable". But this is not an option for me, my bean uses a shared connection.

Comment: @siledh in java EE  with the container you just CANT use synchronized keyword

Comment: @Chechus because that would be considered bad practice or are there any formal limitations? I can't see why synchronized wouldn't work here, it would achieve everything the OP wanted.

Comment: @siledh concurrency is completely managed by the container (that is the idea behind EJB), UNLESS you specify ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN) annotation, an example is: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giptu/index.html , in that case you could use the synchronized and volatile keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SELECT FOR UPDATE to serialize the access of the rows.

With JPA 2 use the LockModeType:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html

```
q.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
```

Comment: Btw. the answer of @MaDa is only valid for JPA 1.0.
Since JPA 2.0 there is the LockModeType which can be used on queries or several EntityManger methods (e.g. refresh, find...)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Wildfly: This is a bug. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4844 describes your problem which will be fixed in Wildfly 10. There the problem is described as a timer problem which might be the same as yours.

My workaround is to seperate the code that does the work into another bean which is called by the outer (timer) bean. The outer bean method is annotated to not start a transaction (`@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)`), so the transaction is started and safely finished in the second new bean.

Comment: If needed, I could provide code fragments from my solution (workaround).

Comment: Could you provide codes? Have you put getAllOpenObjects to another bean?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in JPA (so, in a portable way). Your options might be:

1. Some JPA implementations allow setting isolation level on a per-query basis (e.g. [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.1/apache-openjpa-1.0.1/docs/manual/jpa_overview_query.html#jpa_hints_isolation)), some don't (Hibernate). But even in OpenJPA this hint needs to be implemented in a particular database driver, otherwise it has no effect).
2. Running a native query – consult your database documentation for details.

As a side comment I should say that JPA (and Java EE in general) is not designed with bulk database operations in mind – it's rather for multiple concurrent queries for data items that in most cases don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke from your doSomeStuffAndClose method Stateful Session Bean with implemented [SessionSynchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/SessionSynchronization.html) interface. Than from afterCompletion method in SFSB you can inform singleton bean that data has been commited and can handle another request.

I know that this way we have two really tight coupled beans, but this should solve your problem.

Comment: I thought OP meant to save himself from the possibility of another bean (of any type) accessing any of MyObj records - in which case you suggestion is not valid. But maybe I misinterpreted it.

Comment: @MaDa You can treat SFSB as utility bean only to handle transaction. I interpreted accessing constraint only as concurrent access prevention.

Comment: This would be a possible solution (SessionSynchronization was new to me, thanks for that...) but this approach seems a bit to complicated to me. I think I will solve my problem by dealing with the transaction myself using bean-managed transactions...

Answer (score 0):

You're using container-managed concurrency (the default). In JavaEE 7 (not sure about older ones, but likely yes) the transaction is guaranteed to commit before the method exits, hence before lock is released. From the JavaEE 7 tutorials:

"Typically, the container begins a transaction immediately before an enterprise bean method starts and commits the transaction just before the method exits. Each method can be associated with a single transaction. Nested or multiple transactions are not allowed within a method."
*https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/transactions003.htm#BNCIJ*

If you're experiencing another behavior, check for any cache that might be active (@Cacheable). You may watch another interesting question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790667/timeout-and-container-managed-concurrency-in-singleton

By the way, LockType(WRITE) is also default, you don't need to explicit it. Hence, getAllObjects is also LockType(WRITE).